# What is the class of this javascript button for use with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to produce a selenium script (python) to automate adding things to cart.

I was told in a previous post to try something like:

What is the "class" or element for the size button on this website?

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/dri-fit-cool-tailwind-stripe-running-shirt/pid-10739300/pgid-11072108

I am using chrome dev tools, but apparently I am unable to identify the correct selector so that I can automate clicking the size button with selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would locate it by the `exp-pdp-size-dropdown` class:

```
size_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".exp-pdp-size-dropdown")
```

Note that, in order to open the size dropdown, you would need to hover the button. You can do it via ["driver action chains"](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(size_button).perform()
```